# Can not access Marketplace when updating Jboss plug in to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Can not  access Marketplace when updating Jboss plug in to eclipse.

Hi, I have registered account in eclipse.marketplace site, and I can log in that site without any problem with my id and password.
Then I downloaded eclipse Kepler and unzipped it, and open it in my workstation. Then I tried to install JBoss plug in (following this link: http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/installation/update_3_3)to my eclipse by click Help ->Eclipse Marketplace, then I got a Login required popup window with Username and Password, I entered them, but I can not log in, these are the details error message below:

Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: Stream closed
Does anybody know why I can not log in the marketplace from here? , thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse go to Help -> Install New Software
Type in this URL: http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/indigo/ 
Hit add, and you should then be able to add all of the things you need.

Comment: I tried it, but in the middle of installation, I got a popup window with message: Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity or validity of this software can not be established, ? I hit yes to continue.

Comment: Yes, I think that is a typical message for most plug-ins. Not sure why it throws that warning, but I have seen in several times.